# xml input mapping in dataweave

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

input file is-

```html
<A>
  <B>
    <merchant_ref>icici</merchant_ref>
    <transaction_tag>sdfhisdb</transaction_tag>
    <transaction_type>inquiry</transaction_type>
    <method>valuelink</method>
    <order_number>123</order_number>
    <amount>1000</amount>
    <currency_code>CAD</currency_code>
  </B>
  <B>
    <merchant_ref>icici</merchant_ref>
    <transaction_tag>sdfhisdb</transaction_tag>
    <transaction_type>inquiry</transaction_type>
    <method>valuelink</method>
    <order_number>123</order_number>
    <amount>2000</amount>
    <currency_code></currency_code>
  </B>
  <B/>
  <B>
    <merchant_ref>icici</merchant_ref>
    <transaction_tag>sdfhisdb</transaction_tag>
    <transaction_type>inquiry</transaction_type>
    <method>valuelink</method>
    <order_number>123</order_number>
    <amount>4000</amount>
    <currency_code></currency_code>
  </B>
  <B>
    <merchant_ref>icici</merchant_ref>
    <transaction_tag>sdfhisdb</transaction_tag>
    <transaction_type>inquiry</transaction_type>
    <method>valuelink</method>
    <order_number>123</order_number>
    <amount>5000</amount>
    <currency_code></currency_code>
  </B>
</A>
```

tried to map using the below code in dataweave

```html
 %output application/xml
    ---
    Inquiry: payload.A.*B mapObject
        {
         balanceInquiry:
               { 
                request: {
                    amount:{
                    amount: payload.A.B.amount/1000 as :number,            
                    currency: payload.A.B.currency_code
                           }
                         }
               }
         }
```

I am trying to map each value of B which is under A but every time I get the same first thing 5 times as amount 1.0 whether it should change to 2.0 4.0 and 5.0

Please correct me If I am doing something wrong to achieve all the values of B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using mapObject and not define the parameter (key and value), then you should use its default. The key is defined by default as **$$** and the value as **$**.

Therefore, the (part of) DataWeave code should be:

```
amount: $.amount / 1000 as :number when $.amount != null otherwise 0,
currency: $.currency_code default ""
```

Comment: The problem is I am getting the below output 5 times
  <balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>1.0</amount>
        <currency>CAD</currency>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>  
   whereas amount value in the input varies as 1000 2000 4000 5000, so in out put I should get      <amount>1.0</amount> then    for next   <amount>2.0</amount> and so on

Comment: You get `<amount>1.0</amount>` 5 times because the DataWeave code is incorrect: `payload.A.B.amount`. Replace it with `$.amount`, then you will get the associated value accordingly.

Comment: getting below error Message   
 : Exception while executing: 
            amount: $.amount/1000 as :number when $.amount ~= null otherwise 0,
                                                    ^
Type mismatch
     found :name, :string
  required :name, :object
Type                  : com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Comment: `~=` it must be `!=`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked more why $.amount is not accessible but making some change in your code would make it work. Check below -

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
 Inquiry: payload.A.*B mapObject
    {
        balanceInquiry:
           { 
            request: {
                amount:{
                amount: ($[5]/1000 when $[5] != null otherwise 0) as :number,            
                currency: payload.A.B.currency_code
                       }
                     }
           }
     }
}
```

Output looks like -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Inquiry>
  <balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>1.0</amount>
        <currency>CAD</currency>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>
  <balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>2.0</amount>
        <currency>CAD</currency>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>
  <balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>0</amount>
        <currency>CAD</currency>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>
  <balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>4.0</amount>
        <currency>CAD</currency>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>
  <balanceInquiry>
    <request>
      <amount>
        <amount>5.0</amount>
        <currency>CAD</currency>
      </amount>
    </request>
  </balanceInquiry>
</Inquiry>
```